# Vertical vectors in angle brackets

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I wanted to produce the following formula:

[image: a vertical vector in angle brackets]

which is nothing but a vertical vector in angle brackets. I expected the following code to do the job:

```
\left\langle
    \begin{matrix}
      a  \\
      b  \\
      c  \\
      d  \\
    \end{matrix}
\right\rangle
```

However, the result is:

[image: result]

It seems that, contrary to brackets and parentheses, the angle brackets do not extend beyond some certain limit.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added this as a second solution, based on @mico's comment to my earlier solution. It uses a non-free but no-cost font, [MTPro2 Lite from PCTeX](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html#MTPro2_Lite).

The use of the font to produce large delimiters needs a different syntax as well as loading the font (if a regular user of MTPro2 knows better, please let us know). Unlike `\yhmath` these delimiters can scale to very large matrices (up to 4 inches high, according to the documentation). The syntax is described in detail in section 2.12 of the [MTPro2 LaTeX Guide](http://www.pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{
   \begin{matrix}
      a  \\
      b  \\
      c  \\
      d  \\
      e  \\
      f  \\
      g  \\
      h  \\
    \end{matrix}}$
$\LEFTRIGHT\langle\rangle{
   \begin{matrix}
      a  \\
      b  \\
      c  \\
      d  \\
    \end{matrix}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the above code:]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a TikZ solution.  Not sure I'd recommend it, and it would probably need a little tweaking with regard to spacing as well.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{angmatrix}{%
  \tikz[baseline=0pt]
    \draw[line width=1pt] 
     node[append after command={
      (\tikzlastnode.north west) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.west)+.2*(\tikzlastnode.west)!1!90:(\tikzlastnode.north west)$) -- (\tikzlastnode.south west)
      (\tikzlastnode.north east) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.east)+.2*(\tikzlastnode.east)!1!270:(\tikzlastnode.north east)$) -- (\tikzlastnode.south east)
      }] {\(\begin{matrix} \BODY \end{matrix}\)};}%
{}


\begin{document}
\[
A = 
\begin{angmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ f \\ g
\end{angmatrix}, B = 
\begin{angmatrix}
  a \\ b \\ c
\end{angmatrix}, C = 
\begin{angmatrix}
  a
\end{angmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: angular bracketted matrices]

Comment: Oddly enough, I get this error: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/append after command' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: @Sadeq: Which version of PGF are you using?  I'm on 2.10 so it might be something added in a version between the one you're using and 2.10.  (It's well worth upgrading if you do use TikZ/PGF.)

Comment: Thanks. Mine was 2.0, and upgrading to 2.10 solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `\usepackage{yhmath}` sorts this for me (see `texdoc yhmath` for details)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}

$
\left\langle
    \begin{matrix}
      a  \\
      b  \\
      c  \\
      d  \\
    \end{matrix}
\right\rangle
$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If your typesetting needs require the use of Times Roman fonts, you may also want to look at the MathTime Pro font package (http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html), which has a full set of beautifully designed extra-large operators (up to 4 inches, or 10 cm, high).

Comment: Running my example with `yhmath` then I reach the limit with about 5 characters stacked.

Comment: @Andrew, indeed. In effect, for this usage, `\usepackage{yhmath}` is doing no more than `\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}` (line 3 of the code in section 7 of the documentation). It solves the OP's problem, as stated, but is not a general solution, unlike yours.

Comment: I'm all for solving the problem as stated!  My code is probably overkill, and fonts probably look nice than raw lines.  (I tend to give hacky-type answers on the off-chance that there isn't a "neat" one.)