# Creating Large Math Boundaries

Tags: math-mode

I was wanting to know of a useful way to create large `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle` commands. I have tried all up-sizing commands but get a message that they cannot be used in math mode. Such as:

```
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
```

Also I have tried, `\left\left\langle...\right\right\rangle`

to no working either.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\P{\mathbf{P}}
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}
\def\la{\left\langle}
\def\ra{\right\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 

\P-\Q \;&=\; \large\la (1-(-2)), (2-1), (-1-3) \large\ra \
\;&=\; \la 3, 1, -4 \ra. \
\\                                              

|\P-\Q| \;&=\; \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\

\;&=\; \sqrt{(3)^2 + (1)^2 + (-4)^2} \\

\;&=\; \sqrt{9+1+16} \\

\;&=\; \sqrt{26}

\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you have a look at `\bigl\langle` or `\Biggl\langle` and `\bigr\rangle` or `\Biggr\rangle`?

Comment: @pluton: Do they have anything available that is sort of in the middle of these two sizes. Also, when using `\bigl\langle` in the define command in the preamble, it does not do the auto sizing for display math fractions. But `Biggl\langle...\Biggr\rangle` works just fine for display fractions, but it looks really big for something simple like. <1,2,3>

Comment: There is a related question: [Vertical vectors in angle brackets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26498/6964)

Comment: see `\bigl`,  `\Bigl`,  `\biggl` and `\Biggl`; `\bigr`,  `\Bigr`,  `\biggr` and `\Biggr`; these are constant. They will not self adapt to the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, the fontsize-changing commands `\large`, `\Large`, `\huge`, and `\Huge` work only in text mode. Different commands are required for math mode.

- In math mode, the easiest way to change the height/depth of "fences" -- such as round parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, angle brackets, and many other such delimiters -- is to prefix them with `\left` and `\right` commands, respectively. The height of the fences will be set *automatically*: the fences will be at least as tall as the math material they enclose. A side benefit of using the `\left ...`\right`method is that it provides some useful syntax checking: LaTeX will issue an error message if it cannot match every`\left`statement to a`\right` statement, and vice versa.
- If you want direct control over the size of the fences, you can prefix the fence symbols -- in order of increasing size -- with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`. If you use these statements in pairs, such as `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`, LaTeX will perform some syntax checking for you.
- The *downside* of having such direct control over the size of the fences is that you need to know -- either in advance, or by trial and error -- which size to choose.
- One *upside* to having direct control over the size of the fences is that -- as you've also discovered -- the `\left ... \right` mechanism does not always get the job done. E.g., in the snippet

  ```
  $\left( (a+b) \cdot (c+d) \right)$
  ```

  the outer parentheses will have the exact same size as the inner ones, which is probably not what you're trying to achieve. In such a case, you need to type

  ```
  $\bigl( (a+b) \cdot (c+d) \bigr)$
  ```

  in order to enlarge the outer set of parentheses a bit.
- A second instance where having direct control over the size of the fences is desirable is the case

  ```
  $\displaystyle C \biggl( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \biggr)$
  ```

  because the size of the parentheses generated by the `\left ... \right` method would be too large, typographically speaking.
- A third reason for not using the `\left ... \right` method is that it adds some potentially unwanted whitespace around the fences. One way to avoid this problem is to load the [mleftright](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package and to use the commands `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right`. (If you're sure you'll *always* want to suppress the extra amount of whitespace generated by the `\left` and `\right` commands, you could load the `mleftright` package and issue the instruction `\mleftright` in the preamble; doing so will redefine `\left` and `\right` to act like `\mleft` and `\mright`, respectively.)

  For more information on the whitespace issues created by `\left` and `\right` and how to deal with them, you may want to check out the question [Spacing around \left and \right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/5001).

That said, most of the time you'll be just fine if you use the `\left ... \right` method. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Mico: Thanks Mico, that was some very useful information you gave. I learned something. I like it when I can actually get some background information about a problem to learn more about it along with a solution going about how to overcome it. +1.. Happy TeXing to you as well! `:)`

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\P{\mathbf{P}}
\def\Q{\mathbf{Q}}
\def\la{\left\langle\rule{0pt}{3em}}
\def\ra{\right\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\P-\Q \;&=\; \la (1-(-2)), (2-1), (-1-3) \ra \\
\;&=\; \la 3, 1, -4 \ra. \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbet: Thanks. So to understand. Doing `\rule{0pt}{3em}` for the `\left\langle` does automatically the same for the `\right\rangle`? And could you explain why is that?

Comment: @night owl: the `\left`...`\right` construction automatically resizes the delimiters to fit whatever's inside, so you only need one `\rule` to make both delimiters the right size.

Comment: @night owl: every contents inside math is vertically centered and the largest box inside the math expression is valid for the left _and_ right angles