# How to input the staggered array?

Tags: equations

How to input the staggered array as the expression like this:
[image: hexagonal array]

The expressions are in hexagonal fashion. Are there packages for this situation?

thank you.

Comment: Who comes up with this typography blasphemy?

Comment: Some related questions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/vertical-vectors-in-angle-brackets) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108767/big-angle-brackets).

Comment: seems related: [Using LaTeX to render hypergeometric function notation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2476/579)

Comment: @Null -- those questions refer only to the sizing of angle brackets.  that's not the central problem here.

Comment: Looks like a simple `array` with a few empty cells between to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I use TABstacks to make the data stacks, and the `\scaleleftright[max-width]{left}{content}{right}` to add the brackets.  Note that in the second matrix, I actually use a small negative "tabbedgap" of -1pt (i.e., column sep) to overlap the columns slightly.  By comparison, I use a +1pt gap in the first matrix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,amssymb,amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\setstacktabbedgap{1pt}
A_h = \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\tabbedCenterstack{
&0&&0&\\
0&&0&&0\\
&0&&0&
}}{\rangle}
\text{, and } 
\setstacktabbedgap{-1pt}
B_h =\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\tabbedCenterstack{
&-1&&-1&\\
-1&&6+\varepsilon^2&&-1\\
&-1&&-1&
}}{\rangle}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

While not shown here, uniform column width can be enforced by issuing `\fixTABwidth{T}` prior to the stacks.  In so doing, a change in the tabbedgap is correspondingly called for.

If one really hates typing double `&&`, then this `\active` alternative allows the use of `#` to mean `&&`, producing the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,tabstackengine,amssymb,amsmath}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\catcode`#=\active \def#{&&}
\setstacktabbedgap{1pt}
A_h = \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\tabbedCenterstack{
&0#0&\\
0#0#0\\
&0#0&
}}{\rangle}
\text{, and } 
\setstacktabbedgap{-1pt}
B_h =\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\tabbedCenterstack{
&-1#-1&\\
-1#6+\varepsilon^2#-1\\
&-1#-1&
}}{\rangle}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Three lines are covered by the standard `\left<` and `\right>` symbols.

Here's an `hexagon` environment that can receive an optional argument for setting the width of the cells (default 1em):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,collcell}

\newcolumntype{h}{>{\collectcell\hd}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{@{\hspace{-#1\hexawidth}}}
\newcommand{\hd}[1]{\makebox[\hexawidth]{$#1$}}
\newlength{\hexawidth}

\newenvironment{hexagon}[1][1em]
 {\setlength{\hexawidth}{#1}
  \left<
  \begin{array}{k{.33333}*{4}{hk{.5}}hk{.33333}}}
 {\end{array}\right>}


\begin{document}
\[
A_{h}=
  \begin{hexagon}
    & 0 && 0 \\
  0 && 0 && 0 \\
    & 0 && 0 \\
  \end{hexagon}
\qquad
B_{h}=
  \begin{hexagon}[4em]
    & -1 && -1 \\
  -1 && 6+\varepsilon^2 && -1 \\
    & -1 && -1 \\
  \end{hexagon}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that the `\\` in the last row is necessary because of how `collcell` works.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know `scalerel` and `\scaleleftright` command, so I've copied from Steven's answer. Thanks.

But I knew `array` which can be also used for these expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amsmath,array}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\[
A_h = \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
& 0 & & 0 & \\
0 & & 0 & & 0 \\
& 0 & & 0 &\\
\end{array}}{\rangle}, 
\text{and}\ B_h = 
\scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\langle}{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
& -1 & & -1 & \\
-1 & & 6+\epsilon^2 & & -1 \\
& -1 & & -1 &\\
\end{array}}{\rangle}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]