\langle , \rangle delimiters do not work with tikz matrix
If I try to create a matrix with square brackets and angled brackets
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {matrix,fit}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]
            \matrix(m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=1ex, ampersand replacement=\&, nodes in empty cells, nodes={shape=rectangle,minimum height=2ex, anchor=center},] {
             \& \mbox{\tiny $l = 1$} \& \mbox{\tiny $l = 2$} \\[1 ex]
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 1$ \quad} \&[1 ex]  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{1}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{1}}}$ \\
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 2$ \quad} \& $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{2}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{2}}}$ \\
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 3$ \quad} \& $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{3}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{3}}}$ \\
            };
            \node[fit= (m-2-2.north west) (m-4-3.south east), left delimiter={\langle}, right delimiter={\rangle},inner sep=0ex] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]
            \matrix(m) [matrix of nodes, column sep=1ex, ampersand replacement=\&, nodes in empty cells, nodes={shape=rectangle,minimum height=2ex, anchor=center},] {
             \& \mbox{\tiny $l = 1$} \& \mbox{\tiny $l = 2$} \\[1 ex]
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 1$ \quad} \&[1 ex]  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{1}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{1}}}$ \\
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 2$ \quad} \& $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{2}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{2}}}$ \\
             \mbox{\tiny $k = 3$ \quad} \& $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{1}_{3}}}$ \&  $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tensor{X}{^{2}_{3}}}$ \\
            };
            \node[fit= (m-2-2.north west) (m-4-3.south east), left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},inner sep=0ex] {};
       \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

the result is

Square brackets have a nice fit but angled brackets cannot be scaled to fit any node size.
I have seen a post in which solutions with mtpro2 or \resizebox are used but these do not work in this case. The brackets are fitted inside a matrix and so I cannot apply any of these solutions. Any hints/pointers/solutions would be appreciated.

Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26503/36296

Q705309 advises to use package yhmath. The symbols simply don't scale as good. Try: \[ \left\langle \dfrac{1}{1\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{1}}} \right\rangle \]
