# The gaps in a matrix brackets

Tags: matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broken matrix - gaps in brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23431/broken-matrix-gaps-in-brackets)

I created a matrix in latex, but there are gaps in its brackets. Does anyone how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 var(\theta)& = \begin{bmatrix}
 var(\hat\theta_1) & cov(\hat\theta_1,\hat\theta_2) & \cdots  &      cov(\hat\theta_1,\hat\theta_k) \\
  cov(\hat\theta_2,\hat\theta_1) &  var(\hat\theta_2) & \cdots &      cov(\hat\theta_2,\hat\theta_k) \\
 \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
cov(\hat\theta_k,\hat\theta_1) & cov(\hat\theta_k,\hat\theta_2) &  \cdots &      var(\hat\theta_k)  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *gaps*? Replace the third `\vdots` by `\ddots`.

Comment: Is your problem the same as described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23431/14100)?

Comment: I think you are referring to an artifact. Some viewers often display tiny gaps in the brackets, but they will disappear at a different zoom setting, for example.

Comment: Yes, if I zoom in, the gaps disappear.