# Drawing Linear Process Ball Diagram

Tags: diagrams

Does anyone know how to draw a simple process flow diagram like this?[image: Simple process flow diagram]

Comment: @AAM: I've produced a short code with `pstricks` that reproduces  more or less your image, but I can't post it as an answer since you question has been closed. If you're interested, is there a place where I can upload it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you really wanted to, you could draw it as a tree. The contents of the nodes are shamelessly taken from [R. Schumacher's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241827/).

Here's an example using `forest`.

[image: tree timeline]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      delay={
        label/.wrap pgfmath arg={[font=\sffamily, anchor=west]right:#1}{content()},
        content={},
        circle,
        fill,
        inner sep=1.5pt,
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center
      },
      edge={thick},
      if n children=0{
        l sep+=-15pt,
        append={
          [, edge={thick, -{Triangle[]}}]
        }
      }{}
    }
    [{Ge(100nm)--on--Si substrate}
      [{Hydrogen ion Shower Doping}
        [{Native Oxide Removal (HF:H$_2$O-1:100, 30 sec)}
          [{Ni /TiN (10 nm/10 nm) Deposition}
            [{RTP for germanidation (400$^o$C, 30 sec)}
              [{Post-germanidation Annealing}]]]]]]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your solution. It is much cleaner and usable than modifying a timeline.   I leave my solution as a how not to do it demo :(

Comment: @R.Schumacher Yours feels like less of a 'cheat'. It just seemed too easy to do it this way, somehow. I mostly thought of it because of your comment about difficulty adding the arrow: I thought 'if it were a tree, that wouldn't be a problem'. And then I realised that it was possible to see it as a tree where the number of children was always 1.... Your code looks more impressive, though ;).

Comment: I taught Technical Writing Using LaTeX for 18 years to undergraduate math majors (Freshman and Sophomores).  Almost my number one rule was keep it simple and clean.  And a close second was never reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This is a close version of what you want.  I have modified the code from [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline/197140#197140)  The only item missing is the bottom arrow (Still thinking about that)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

% code by Andrew:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\makeatletter
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\makeatletter
\def&{\iftikz@is@matrix
  \pgfmatrixnextcell
  \else
  \matamp
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline
\tikzset{description/.style={
  column 2/.append style={#1}
 },
 timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
 timeline color=red!80!black,
 timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
 use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
 use timeline header=false,
 add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
 add bottom line=false,
 timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
 timeline title={},
 line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
 line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
\setcounter{lines}{1}%
\stepcounter{vtml}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
 column 2/.style={anchor=west},
 text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
 row sep=1ex,
 column sep=1em,
 #1
]
\matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}
\path[timeline color st] 
($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);
\foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
 \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick] 
 (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at 
 ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
 \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
 }
 \ifvtimelinetitle%
  \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
  ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);
  \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
   at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west) 
%   {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};% Original line
   {\textit{\vtimelinetitle}};% Modified Line
 \else%
  \relax%
 \fi%
 \ifvtimebottomline%
   \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
  ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
 \else%
   \relax%
 \fi%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vtimeline}[description={text width=10cm}, 
 row sep=2ex, 
 use timeline header,
 timeline title={Simple Process Flow Ball Diagram}]
\quad  & Ge(100nm)--on--Si substrate\endlr
\quad  & Hydrogen ion Shower Doping\endlr
\quad  & Native Oxide Removal (HF:H$_2$O-1:100, 30 sec)\endlr
\quad  & Ni /TiN (10 nm/10 nm) Deposition\endlr
\quad  & RTP for germanidation (400$^o$C, 30 sec)\endlr
\quad  & Post-germanidation Annealing\endlr
\end{vtimeline}

\end{document}
```

[image]