# Redefine norm symbol \| as \left\| or \right\|

Tags: macros

I'm  currently using the following macro:

```
\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}
```

Is it possible to redefine `\|` so that `\|\frac{a}{b}\|` produces the same output as `\norm{\frac{a}{b}}`?

Why? Not only I find easier and clearer to write `\|\frac{a}{b}\|`, but, most importantly, I realized my text editor can display `\|` as the unicode norm symbol, which really improves readability.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You may want to consult [Peter Grill's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43009/5001) to the query about [Absolute Value and Norm Symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43008/5001) for an improved `\norm` macro. Incidentally, which text editor do you use?

Comment: @Mico: According to the user name the editor is "vim" ;-)

Comment: You seem to start from the assumption that using `\left` and `\right` in every situation is good. It isn't.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- I was just curious if the user name had some real information content...

Comment: @Mico: In the case of my username : yes, that's a lot of information ;-)

Comment: Would the intent be to **only** use `\|` as a paired delimiter, and **never** in any other context?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- My username is only half as informative as yours. But then, my avatar is a bit more unusual... :-)

Comment: @Mico: If you're not a mean criminal on the planet Tattoine, everything is fine ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend against redefining things like `\|`, but it can be done, **if** it is **only** to be used in this paired-delimiter context. (The original definition of `\|` is now saved in `\svvert`).  As egreg notes in a comment, nesting also causes problems, unless the nested terms are grouped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svvert\|
\def\norm#1{\left\svvert#1\right\svvert}
\def\|#1\|{\norm{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\|\frac{A}{B}\|
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which of course would fail in cases such as `$\|\|A\| B\|=\|A\| \|B\|$`

Comment: What would I have to do if I wanted to redefine the macros `\left\{#1\right\}`? I can't handle those braces...

Comment: @Ktree I don't recommend, for the same reasons cited in the answer, but `\documentclass{article}
\let\svlb\{
\let\svrb\}
\def\emb#1{\left\svlb#1\right\svrb}
\def\{#1\}{\emb{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\{\frac{A}{B}\}
\]
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thanks a lot, I know it's not good to redefine `\left` or `\right` and I won't do that. The reason why I'm thinking of that is that I redefined my matrix environments like in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/92996 for beamer presentations. Unfortunatelly, there are some parts where I use `\left[...\right]` (or `\{\}`) (e.g. to surround arrays). Now I tried to sort of redefine this, but I think there is no other way than introducing a new command, e.g. `\leftbrack...\rightbrack`. Or do you know a way?

Comment: @Ktree I strongly recommend introducing a uniquely named command to achieve what it is you desire.  That is the preferred practice for LaTeX.