# How to change caption style and location of a vertical timeline with tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, tikz-styles

I found this code in [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline). But I want the caption below my timeline and need to change TIMELINE 1 to Table 1. Could you help me to get this?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

% code by Andrew:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\makeatletter
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\makeatletter
\def&{\iftikz@is@matrix
  \pgfmatrixnextcell
  \else
  \matamp
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline
\tikzset{description/.style={
  column 2/.append style={#1}
 },
 timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
 timeline color=red!80!black,
 timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
 use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
 use timeline header=false,
 add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
 add bottom line=false,
 timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
 timeline title={},
 line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
 line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
\setcounter{lines}{1}%
\stepcounter{vtml}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
 column 2/.style={anchor=west},
 text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
 row sep=1ex,
 column sep=1em,
 #1
]
\matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}
\path[timeline color st] 
($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);
\foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
 \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick] 
 (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at 
 ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
 \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
 }
 \ifvtimelinetitle%
  \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
  ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);
  \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
   at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west) 
   {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};
 \else%
  \relax%
 \fi%
 \ifvtimebottomline%
   \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
  ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
 \else%
   \relax%
 \fi%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vtimeline}[description={text width=7cm}, 
 row sep=4ex, 
 use timeline header,
 timeline title={The title}, add bottom line]
1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\endlr
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
\end{vtimeline}
\end{document}**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `vtimeline` environment, remove the options `use timeline header` and `timeline title`, and use a standard `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

% code by Andrew:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\makeatletter
\def&{\iftikz@is@matrix
  \pgfmatrixnextcell
  \else
  \matamp
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline
\tikzset{description/.style={
  column 2/.append style={#1}
 },
 timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
 timeline color=red!80!black,
 timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
 use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
 use timeline header=false,
 add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
 add bottom line=false,
 timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
 timeline title={},
 line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
 line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
\setcounter{lines}{1}%
\stepcounter{vtml}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
 column 2/.style={anchor=west},
 text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
 row sep=1ex,
 column sep=1em,
 #1
]
\matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}
\path[timeline color st] 
($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);
\foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
 \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick] 
 (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at 
 ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
 \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
 }
 \ifvtimelinetitle%
  \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
  ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);
  \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
   at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west) 
   {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};
 \else%
  \relax%
 \fi%
 \ifvtimebottomline%
   \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
  ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
 \else%
   \relax%
 \fi%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{vtimeline}[description={text width=7cm}, 
 row sep=4ex, 
% use timeline header,
% timeline title={The title},
 add bottom line]
% 1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\endlr
% 1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
% 1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
% 1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
% 1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
% 1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
% 1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
\end{vtimeline}
\caption{my special timeline}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```