# Fitting the timelines to textwidth and also skipping to the nextline

Tags: timeline, moderntimeline

I have some problems with the timelines:

1. I want to fit the timeline to the text width and also want to center.
2. How can we skip to the next line?

If same date (for example 1941) includes three or four lines, the texts are intertwined. Maybe we skip to nextline. ( or Maybe incerasing row sep more is another solution but then When the line spacing is too much, it does not look nice.)

``

```
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
%Code by Claudio:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197447/221452
% Uses code by Andrew:
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\makeatletter
    \let\matamp=&
    \catcode`\&=13
    \def&{%
        \iftikz@is@matrix%
            \pgfmatrixnextcell%
        \else%
            \matamp%
        \fi%
    }
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline

\tikzset{
    description/.style={column 2/.append style={#1}},
    timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
    timeline color=red!80!black,
    timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
    use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
    use timeline header=false,
    add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
    add bottom line=false,
    timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
    timeline title={},
    line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
    line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
    \setcounter{lines}{1}%
    \stepcounter{vtml}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
        column 2/.style={anchor=west},
        text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
        row sep=1ex,
        column sep=1em,
        #1
    ]
        \matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}

        \path[timeline color st]
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);

        \foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
            \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick]
            (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at
            ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
                \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
        }

        \ifvtimelinetitle%
            \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
                ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);

            \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
                at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west)
                {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};
        \else%
            \relax%
        \fi%

        \ifvtimebottomline%
            \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
            ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
        \else%
            \relax%
        \fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}  





\begin{document}
      \begin{center} 
        \begin{vtimeline}[description={text width=\textwidth},
                row sep=4ex,
                use timeline header,
                timeline title={The timeline of the Lorem Ipsum}]
                1921 & Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \endlr 
                1941 &  It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. \endlr
                1991 & Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
            \end{vtimeline}
        \end{center}
\end{document}
```

``